# Drag and drop vue 3, render each item separately

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, vuejs3, vue-component, draggable

I'm currently using laravel/inertiajs/vue3 to make a school planning web application,
where the user has a calendar (monday->friday), that he can add classes to it using drag and drop,
then when the user finishes, he can save the planning and can visit it whenever he wants.
My problem is that I want to render each column item separately for example :
monday:{row1:class1, row2:class2 ...}, tuesday:{....},..
but I don't know how I can achieve that.

I tried all of the following systems:
**vuedraggable@next
gridstackjs
Vue Grid Layout
VueDragDrop**

**gridstackjs** worked good, but i don't know how i can render each class in it's proper column/row.

I tried this using vuedraggable, but I don't seem to find a way to render each column separatly

```js
            <table class="w-full border-collapse bg-white text-left text-sm text-gray-500">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableHeadItem class="w-10">
                        Head
                    </TableHeadItem>
                    <template v-for="item in items">
                        <TableHeadItem>
                            {{ item.name }}
                        </TableHeadItem>
                    </template>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    <TableRow>
                        <draggable v-model="itemsCopy" item-key="name" @end="handleDragEnd">
                            <template #item="{ element }">
                                <TableRowItem class="h-52 w-52 text-center border">
                                    {{ element.name }}
                                </TableRowItem>
                            </template>
                        </draggable>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
            </table>
```

thanks in advance